# How to write a Spark dataframe into cassandra parallelly?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe which contains around 100k records. Now I want to write this dataframe into Cassandra but this write should be in parallel.
So how is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [datasax spark cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md)

you can find an example to persist dataframe [here](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/14_data_frames.md)

```
    import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._

df.write
  .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
  .options(Map("table" -> "words_copy", "keyspace" -> "test", "cluster" -> "cluster_B"))
  .save()

df.write
  .cassandraFormat("words_copy", "test", "cluster_B")
  .save()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ..But Sir in my case the size of dataframe is around  500k records ..When I write this whole dataframe into Cassandra using your first statement then it is taking too much time...So Is there any approach for writing this dataframe into cassandra in parallel?

Comment: how do you run your spark job ? are you using Yarn ?

Comment: Yes Sir ..we are using Yarn

Comment: Actually I am getting data from Kafka then I create a df ..but when df contains 4-5 lakhs records and I write this dataframe into Cassandra then it is taking too much time.

Comment: try to add more resources to your spark job . I believe that spark parallelize the data persistance

Comment: When I write a dataframe of 4-5 lakhs records into Cassandra then it takes around 6-7 minutes. So I think if I can write it in parallel into Casandra then i can decrease its time of insertion into Cassandra. So is it possible ?.

Comment: Can you post your spark submit job param ?

Comment: Spark mecanism parralelize data persistance . Allocate more ressources with yarn and your traitement will be more fast .  Read this article https://dzone.com/articles/enable-distributed-data-processing-for-cassandra-w

Comment: Thank You for your valuable suggestions. :)